# Change two arrays into one associative array

Tags: jquery, arrays, associative

I have this 2 following functions, to fill an array with value. I want to fill only 1 array instead of 2. How can I make an associative array ?

```
var itemMetaArray = [];
var itemLabelArray = [];

$('.frm_pro_form input, .frm_pro_form select, .frm_pro_form textarea').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('type') != 'hidden' && ($(this).attr("type") != "submit")) {
        itemMetaArray.push($(this).attr("name"));
    }
});

$('.frm_form_field label').each(function(){
    itemLabelArray.push($(this).text());
});

console.log(itemMetaArray);
console.log(itemLabelArray);
```

```html
<div id="frm_field_71_container" class="frm_form_field form-field frm_top_container"> 
  <label for="field_p0hth" class="frm_primary_label">  
    Date 
    <span class="frm_required"></span> 
  </label> 
  <input type="text" id="field_p0hth" name="item_meta[71]" value="" maxlength="10" class="frm_date" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly JS does not have associative arrays, although an object will do what you require. Secondly, what does your HTML look like? How do the `label` relate to the `input`?

Comment: Here is the HTML : <div id="frm_field_71_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container">
    <label for="field_p0hth" class="frm_primary_label">Date
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="field_p0hth" name="item_meta[71]" value=""  maxlength="10" class="frm_date"  />
</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly JS does not have associative arrays. You can use an object instead. To create the object you simply need to loop through the required inputs, retrieve the related `label` and set the key/value as needed. Try this:

```js
var output = {};

$('.frm_pro_form :input:not(:hidden, :submit)').each(function() {
  var key = $(this).closest('div').find('label').text().trim();
  output[key] = $(this).val();
});

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="frm_pro_form">
  <div id="frm_field_71_container" class="frm_form_field form-field frm_top_container">
    <label for="field_p0hth" class="frm_primary_label">
      Date #1
      <span class="frm_required"></span> 
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="field_p0hth" name="item_meta[71]" value="foo" maxlength="10" class="frm_date" />
  </div>
  <div id="frm_field_72_container" class="frm_form_field form-field frm_top_container">
    <label for="field_p0hth" class="frm_primary_label">
      Date #2
      <span class="frm_required"></span> 
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="field_p1hth" name="item_meta[72]" value="bar" maxlength="10" class="frm_date" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Woaw, amazing. Thanks a lot !